# C# how to search a list

Tags: c#

I have a list of strings like:

List myList

How can I search the list using the .Find() method and see if a specific value exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the generic List.Find:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(VS.80).aspx

You call `myList.Find(x => x == testValue);` if you're using C# 3 and looking for the value '`testvalue`'.  You can put a more advanced condition instead of just "`x == testValue`" too.

Depending on the context, you might want to use `x.Equals(testValue)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
        List<string> myList = new List<string>();
        bool isFound = myList.Contains("abc");
```