# Parse PDF file to memory and perform search for certain value

Tags: c#, itext

I am rather new to the whole C# thing and trying to learn it in more practical way to gather more interest and understanding. I have a code that is parsing PDF https://slicedinvoices.com/pdf/wordpress-pdf-invoice-plugin-sample.pdf file and functioning good. However I would like to write to memory instead of console, in order to search for InvoiceNumber from it later.

My current code for writing into console:

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace PDF_file_reader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<int> InvoiceNumbers = new List<int>();

            string filePath = @"C:\temp\parser\Invoice_Template.pdf";
            int pagesToScan = 2;

            string strText = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath);

                for (int page = 1; page <= pagesToScan; page++) //(int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++) <- for scanning all the pages in A PDF
                {
                    ITextExtractionStrategy its = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
                    strText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its);

                    strText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strText)));
                    //creating the string array and storing the PDF line by line
                    string[] lines = strText.Split('\n');
                    foreach (string line in lines)
                    {
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine($"<{line}>");
                            Console.WriteLine(line.ToString());
                        }
                    }

                    Console.Read();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an output in console:

[image]

How to write to InvoiceNumbers list instead of Console what I am doing now and perform search out of it? I guess with my current setup search would be not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a note, you have an extra set of `{` `}` in your `foreach` loop surrounding `Console.Writeline()` that you can remove.

If you want to store the whole invoice number as it is highlighted in your screenshot ("INV-3337" instead of just "3337"), `InvoiceNumbers` needs to be a list of strings, not ints.

I assume the invoice is always going to be the same, or the number is always going to be the same format (i.e. "Invoice Number 'INV-####"), you could just add a line in your `foreach` loop. Since each `line` is a string, you can check if `line` contains "Invoice Number". If it does, you can add it to `InvoiceNumbers` and remove the phrase "Invoice Number". Then trim it to get rid of any whitespace. Either above or below `Console.Writeline(line.ToString());` you would just add:

```
if (line.Contains("Invoice Number"))
    InvoiceNumbers.Add(line.Replace("Invoice Number", "").Trim());
```

(I used `Replace()` instead of `Remove()` because you would either need to know the start and end positions of the phrase you want to remove. In my opinion, `Replace()` is the safest route for this particular situation)

You can add `break;` to the `if` statement if that's all you're looking for as well. This will stop the `foreach` loop. Once you extract the invoice number, there is no reason to look through the rest of the document, unless you have multiple invoices in one document.

```
if (line.Contains("Invoice Number"))
{
    InvoiceNumbers.Add(line.Replace("Invoice Number", "").Trim());
    break;
}
```

If you want to search through the list for a particular invoice number, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447579/c-sharp-how-to-search-a-list) should help with that.

This is *assuming* that the only difference would be the actual number. If it's not, you could always look into [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8) and have it look for a pattern like "INV-\d*". That would also be assuming the invoice number format is always the same.